# Iphone app update notification not getting from app store to My iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not getting my app update Notification to Iphone/Ipad.Can any one help me about this issues. Except my app not getting but all other apps are showing update notifications. Can any one help me please.

Comment: Have you used [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy)

Comment: No...i didn't used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Harpy checks a user's currently installed version of your iOS app
>   against the version that is currently available in the App Store. If a
>   new version is available, an alert can be presented to the user
>   informing them of the newer version, and giving them the option to
>   update the application.

Link - https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy